# The JSONObject(Map copyFrom) construct function work with different result between Genymotion and other emulator

Tags: android, genymotion

The test code snippet just like below

```
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    list.add(1L);
    list.add(2L);
    jsonMap.put("list", list);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonMap);

    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(list);
    try {
        json.put("JSONArray", ja);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (json != null) {
        System.out.println(json.toString());
        return;
    }
```

The output with Genymotion

```
{"JSONArray":[1,2],"list":"[1, 2]"}
```

With ADT emulator or my nexus 4 phone is

```
{"JSONArray":[1,2],"list":[1,2]}
```

What happen?

Comment: It doesn't in my genymotion. Which genymotion version and android version are you trying on?

Answer (score 2):

I finally reproduced your issue on a 4.1.1 Genymotion device, but also on a 4.1.1 real physical device, as pictured below: (samsung galaxy s2 running cyanogen).

[image: Samsung Galaxy S2 physical device]

So, I would call this behavior a Genymotion feature. ;)
You will see the same behavior on a 4.1.2 ADT emulator.

You are probably experiencing differencies between Android versions. You must handle the two cases to be on the safe side.

Comment: I use another way to avoid this problem，Thank u。 But I have interesting about the different implement。I read this Class's source code of Android, but have no idea.could u help me to point out ？